# Why is Audition CC 2019 (a.k.a. 12.x) is missing from Thor (a.k.a. Creative Cloud Desktop)?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-creative-cloud, adobe-audition

Why is Audition CC 2019 (a.k.a. 12.x) is missing from Thor (a.k.a. Creative Cloud Desktop)? The installed Adobe Audition CC is 2018, Build 11.1.1.3., on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, with the latest Creative Cloud Desktop version (4.8.1.435).

[image]

Before the Creative Cloud Desktop update last week that removed all except the last ~two versions from their servers, I had the same issue:

[image]

To access the other versions' menu:

[image]

Comment: Is your Creative Cloud itself up to date? Adobe have recently [last week] removed all except the last two versions from their servers. You can no longer access anything older than CC2018.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, Up to date (sorry I should have mentioned it, I'll edit the question accordingly)

Comment: How do you access that 'other versions' menu? I'm on Mac & can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Tetsujin To access the other versions' menu: I added the information at the end of the question. (I think it is a bad idea to have a nested menu for just 2 items)

Comment: Interesting - I'd looked in there & in Manage all I have is Uninstall, unfortunately.

Comment: @Tetsujin weird, which version of Adobe Audition is installed on your computer?

Comment: I don't actually have Audition, but I've checked in all the apps I do have & I see no 'other versions' item in any of them.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's surprising.  if you send me a screenshot/gif showing absence of other version menu item + Creative Cloud Desktop version + OS version I'll file a bug report.

Comment: I made a composite of a couple - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXSMT.png

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, what's your Creative Cloud Desktop version + OS version?

Comment: CC4.8.1.435, macOS 10.14.5

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, bug filed, if one day you happen to talk to Adobe tech support, that's JIRA ticket THOR-4191882.

Comment: @Tetsujin Would you be willing to share the logs from your machine using log collector tool https://helpx.adobe.com/in/creative-cloud/kb/cc-log-collector.html to the Adobe technical support?

Comment: tbh, I'm not a fan of the idea. It's not even something that bothers me that it's missing, as I don't need the older versions.

Comment: @Tetsujin no worries, I understand

Comment: @Tetsujin I am told that "other version" menu item is absent 1. When the user is a trial user. or 2. when the subscription of user got expired. -> is that your case?

Comment: i've trials of some things, but not all.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, do you see the "other version" menu item for the program(s) you have subscribed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audition CC 2019 (a.k.a. 12.x) is missing from Thor (a.k.a. Creative Cloud Desktop) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, with the latest Creative Cloud Desktop version (4.8.1.435), because Audition CC 2019  [requires](https://web.archive.org/web/20190516224900/https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/system-requirements.html) Microsoft® Windows 10 (64 bit) version 1703 or higher. The Creative Cloud Desktop fails to notify users about it, and as a result, users don't see the latest versions of some Adobe products, unless they update to Microsoft Windows 10.